# Detect if Debugger is Attached *and* stepping through

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am aware of the `Debugger` class within the `System.Diagnostics` namespace which has the `IsAttached` property.

Is there a property, somewhere, that can augment this call and tell me if we're actually stepping through code, rather than simply just being attached?  I understand this may be highly unlikely, but it would be useful to know.

**EDIT**

Perhaps a better question, rather than "stepping" is running some code:

1. When the debugger "breaks" for the first time (enters debug mode, after being attached)
2. When it runs again (but is still attached, but not "stepping through").

Comment: Looks interesting... what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm curious what use this would have? Can you give an example? You could only detect if you were stepping through (if that's possible) if you were stepping through the line doing the detecting.

Comment: @hatchet, I have some code that runs on a relatively short timer that expires some pooled objects.  Runtime, this works fine - when stepping through the code it can cause issues.  There are alternatives, ones which I will most likely employ for robustness purposes - but thought I'd pose this question. :)

Comment: I think not that there is a method or property on any class in the .NET Framework that provides you the required information. The debugger of the system that is used to debug the application is stored in the registry under **DbgManagedDebugger** (vsjitdebugger.exe)

Comment: Lets say that they're not stepping through. On the line immediately *after* `bool answer = MadeUpFunctionToDetectStepping()`, they've got a breakpoint set. When the breakpoint is hit, the user continues to step through the rest of your code. Without solving the halting problem on both the current program and the debugger (based on current breakpoints, conditional breakpoints, etc), and possibly requiring a time machine, there's no way that `answer` will be true, and yet they are stepping through the code by the time that you examine that variable in your code.

Comment: There are some [unmanaged interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404484.aspx) to handle the debugging of a program that is executing in the common language runtime (CLR). Of interest would be [ICorDebugStepper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233136.aspx)

Comment: You cannot detect in code that the debugger is stepping, because while the code is running, it never is stepping. More precisely, "step" is really implemented as (more or less) "run with an implicit breakpoint on the next line". And that is detected by IsAttached.

Comment: @Jehof, interesting set of interfaces.  @Damien_The_Unbeliever, perhaps a better wording - rather than asking if they're stepping through, detect that we've entered a `break` state, and when we've left that state, not just that they're stepping through the code.

Comment: @Moo-Juice "detect that we've entered a break state" -> sure, but code that is trying to detect this has to be running. Code can never be executing while in a break state, or vice versa.

Comment: But again, you need to have your time machine handy because by the time you *react* to whatever state you've detected, the state may be different.

Comment: The only possible reason I can think of to do what you're trying to do is to make cracking your application difficult.  Unless you're trying to make someone's life a living hell - I think you're probably going about solving whatever problem you have the wrong way.

Comment: @syllogism, indeed!  Hence my comment above that I do have an alternative, one which I am going to use - but thought I'd pose the question anyway.

Comment: My use case: I have a property getter that I want to raise
an exception when being read in an invalid state. Except when
observing the object in the QuickWatch window of the debugger (because in my framework raising the exception also causes logging, and I don't wan to pollute the logfile while QuickWatching).
I know about the _Enable property evaluation..._ configuration
setting of the debugger but I don't want to disable that globally;
I would like an exceptional behaviour for this class only — if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the debugger state from the Debugger.CurrentMode property.  But that's only going to tell you whether it is currently in the break state or if the program is running.  There is no "step" mode, that's a fleeting moment which pretty much ensures that, if you could find about it, that acting on it would already be too late.  Practically guaranteed to be a threading race.

Comment: Excellent.  In essence, the break state was what I was hoping for.  Still, I won't be designing around it - but it's definitely a nice to know and kinda what I was looking for.

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Debugger` does not have `CurrentMode` property,
only [EnvDTE.Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debugger.currentmode.aspx)
has it. I'm afraid this is accessible for VS extensions only, not the program being debugged.